# Create a list of lists. Modify elements in the list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, for-loop, matrix

Requirement:

Define the function `createMatDimXDim(dim)`
This function receives a positive integer number greater or equal than 2 and returns a square matrix of dimension dim x dim, where the contents are numbers which are equal to the row number multiplied by 10 plus the column number.

Expected output:

```
print (createMatDimXDim (4)) 
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [10, 11, 12, 13], [20, 21, 22, 23], [30, 31, 32, 33]]
```

My code:

```
def createMatDimXDim (dim):
    lis=[[0] for i in range(dim)]
    for i in range(dim):
        lis[i][0]=i*10
        for i in range(dim):
           lis[i].append(int(lis[i][0])+1)
    return lis
```

Ouput of my code:

```
[[0, 1, 1, 1, 1], [10, 1, 11, 11, 11], [20, 1, 1, 21, 21], [30, 1, 1, 1, 31]]
```

I wanted to do this:

```
lis[i].append(int(lis[i][i-1])+1)
```

But it gives me an `IndexError`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def createMatDimXDim (dim):
    lis=[[0] for i in range(dim)]
    for i in range(dim):
        lis[i][0]=i*10
        for j in range(dim-1):               # for the nested loop you need to use a new 
                                             # variable j
           lis[i].append(int(lis[i][j])+1)
    return lis

createMatDimXDim(4)
# [[0, 1, 2, 3], [10, 11, 12, 13], [20, 21, 22, 23], [30, 31, 32, 33]]
```

Another option with list comprehension:

```
dim = 4
[[i * 10 + j for j in range(dim)] for i in range(dim)]
# [[0, 1, 2, 3], [10, 11, 12, 13], [20, 21, 22, 23], [30, 31, 32, 33]]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def createMatDimXDim(dim):
    return [[j for j in range(i*10, i*10+dim)] for i in range(dim)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a 2D list comprehension.

```
def createMatDimXDim(dim):
    return [[j for j in range(i*10, i*10+dim)] for i in range(dim)]
createMatDimXDim(4)
```

Output:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [10, 11, 12, 13], [20, 21, 22, 23], [30, 31, 32, 33]]
```

Answer (score 1):

An easy understandable way to do would be:

```
def createMatDimXDim (dim):
    lis=[[0] for i in range(dim)]
    for i in range(dim):
        lis[i][0]=i*10
        for j in range(dim-1):                                    
           lis[i].append(int(lis[i][j])+1)
    return lis

createMatDimXDim(4)
```

Output:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [10, 11, 12, 13], [20, 21, 22, 23], [30, 31, 32, 33]]
```